# 2 different operation modes for a motor

Tags: motor

i want to press "unu" button of the remote, and the motor to rotate continuously, and when i press "sound" i want the motor to rotate untill the hall sensor detects a magnetic field. any ideas please?
in this configuration, even if i press "unu" or "sound", the motor rotates untill the hall sensor detects a magnetic field.

```
#include <TLE94112.h>
#include <Tle94112Motor.h>
#include <IRremote.h>

#define unu 0x1
#define sound 0x55

int RECV_PIN = 2;
int hallSensorPin1 = 3;
int state1;
int oldState1 = 1;

Tle94112 controller = Tle94112();
Tle94112Motor motor1(controller);

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{ irrecv.enableIRIn();
  controller.begin();

  motor1.connect(motor1.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_HB1);
  motor1.connect(motor1.LOWSIDE, controller.TLE_HB2);
  motor1.setPwm(motor1.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_PWM2);
  motor1.setPwmFreq(motor1.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_FREQ200HZ);

  motor1.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume();
  }//add bracket here

  if (results.value == unu || results.value == 0x801 || results.value == 0x2049) {
    motor1.start(63);
  }

  if (results.value == sound || results.value == 0x55 || results.value == 0x2103 || results.value == 0x837 || results.value == 0x37) {
    motor1.start(63);

    oldState1 = 1;
    state1 = digitalRead(hallSensorPin1);

    if (state1 == LOW && oldState1 == 1) {
      motor1.coast();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your observation. i fixed this.

Comment: the two `if (results.value ==` statements execute the same code

Comment: yes, and i tried the configuration that you can see now in the initial post (i updated it) and this one works fine for continuous rotation, but when the magnetic field is detected, the motor receives small pulses without pressing any button, and again when its not detecting a magnetic field, rotates normally till it finds again the magnetic field.

Comment: introduce a layer of separation between `if (results.value ==` and `motor1.start(63);` .... the `if` statement should only set two flags, `motorOn` and `motorMode` (you pick names) .... there should be only one code line that turns on the motor `if (motorOn) {` .... the hall sensor code should be wrapped in `if (motorMode) {`

Comment: you provided incomplete information ... i see nothing in your post about the serial monitor output

Comment: ` Serial.println(results.value, HEX); ` this is what you saying?

Comment: yes, that prints debugging information to serial monitor

Comment: its not showing anything in the serial monitor. im a beginner in arduino, i just used it with a couple of sensors before and this project it is too much for me now i think. anyway i figured out the problem. can i ask how that serial monitor output influence the program?

Comment: it should be printing something when you press a button on the remote control